# scanner in java not working on my machine

Tags: java

```
public class CollectionTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //create Scanner instance to get input from User
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.err.println("Please enter first number to add : ");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter second number to add :");
        int num = scanner.nextInt();

        //adding two numbers in Java by calling method
       int result = add(number, num);

       System.out.printf(" Addition of numbers %d and %d is %d %n", number, num, result);
    }

    public static int add(int number, int num){
        return number + num;
    }
}
```

I wonder what's wrong with this code.When I run this program on my new laptop this works fine.
But on my old pc it gives some error.
Please help me out.Thnx in advance.d

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely the difference is in the machine. Do the laptops use the same OS? More importantly, are you giving them the exact same input? (Use a `.txt` file that you feed into the script instead of typing if you want to be extra-sure.)

Comment: what version of jdk is installed on your PC? Check if your jdk version is 5 or greater than that.

Comment: show full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your pc's java version.

Java Scanner is included from a specific version.java.util.Scanner was introduced in version 1.5 ("Java 5"). Make sure you have the same the java version 1.5 or higher on your old machine.

Download new version of jvm and jre from their site and then try.

Answer (score 0):

[java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) was introduced in version 1.5 ("Java 5"). Make sure you have the same the java version 1.5 or higher on your old machine.